# how to append object to formData in vuejs

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, axios, form-data

I can't append an object to FormData

I use Axios

I don't want to send data by `JSON.stringify()`

```
data () {
   return {
      product: {

          title: '',

          description: '',

          properties: {
             property1: '',
             property2: ''
          }
      }
   }
}
```

I want this

‍‍

```
{title: '', description: '', properties:{property1: '', property2: ''}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `Object.entries`. For example...

```
// If this is the object you want to convert to FormData...
const item = {
    description: 'First item',
    price: 13,
    photo: File
};

const formData = new FormData();

Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    formData.append(key, value);
});

// At this point, you can then pass formData as the payload to axios
```

Read more about `Object.entries()` over here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries